# Using Akka.net.io with SSL

Tags: akka.net

I have successfully written an Akka.net actor that communicates using `System.Tcp()`, how can I now convert this to use SSL?

I can't find anywhere on the Akka.net web site, except for [this posting](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/788) on github, which says 'it'll be done soon' in 2015.

Comment: There was not so much work over it, as akka.net team was working over optimizing Akka.IO internals (see PR: [#2683](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pulls)). Right now SSL support over it was not so much a requested issue, but you can track it here: [#2750](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/2750).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone ever asks this question again, my solution was to create an Actor that implemented a tcp connection with optional SSL (using `SSLStream`) that was compatible with the original `System.Tcp()`.